# Pandas dataframe values refuse to be evaluated as floats with `.apply(eval)`. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using Python 3.4, I have a Pandas Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.head()
```

giving

```
    animal    fraction_decimal
0    cat1      '2/7'
1    cat2      '4/55'
2    cat3      '22/195'
3    cat4      '6/13'
....
```

I would like to evaluate the values in column `fraction_decimal` to become floats, i.e.

```
    animal     fraction_decimal
0    cat1      0.2857142857142857
1    cat2      0.07272727272727272
2    cat3      0.11282051282051282
3    cat4      0.46153846153846156
....
```

However, using `.apply(eval)` simply doesn't work.

I tried

```
df['fraction_decimal'].apply(eval)
```

but this outputs:

```
0           2/7
1           4/55
2           22/195
3           6/13
....
Name: fraction_decimal, dtype: object
```

Why doesn't this work? How can this work properly?

Comment: What are the actual types of elements in that column?  `str`? `fractions.Fraction`?  If the latter, have you tried `.apply(float)`?

Comment: @jedwards It's the former

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval("4/2")

2
```

---

```
eval("'4/2'")

'4/2'
```

---

```
eval(eval("'4/2/'"))

2
```

You have quote characters in your strings.  You need to strip them out.

consider:

```
s = pd.Series(["'1/2'", "'3/4'", "'4/5'", "'6+5'", "'11-7'", "'9*10'"])
```

Then:

```
s.str.replace(r'[\'\"]', '').apply(eval)

0     0.50
1     0.75
2     0.80
3    11.00
4     4.00
5    90.00
dtype: float64
```